# Pushing to nested array inside specific element of parent array (MongoDB)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I'm rethinking how I want to structure some data which is currently being stored in the `Users` Collection. Previously, my server would receive messages, find the user document with the right `profile.website` field, and push an item into the `profile.siteMessages` array:

```
{
  "_id": "hr9ck5Fis5YuvqCqP",
  "profile": {
    "website": "localhost",
    "siteMessages": [
         {
            "text": "sddsd",
            "createdAt": 1482001227204
         },
     ]
  }
}
```

Id like to change the structure to look something like the following. Instead of storing all messages, of which multiple messages could come from the same user, in a top level array in `profile`, I would have a `profile.siteVisitors` field which contains a `visitorId` and then the array of messages:

```
{
  "_id": "dgfsdfdfsdf",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "user2@test.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "profile": {
    "website": "localhost",
    "siteVisitors:" [
        {
          "visitorId": "74585242",
          "messages": [
            {
              "text": "A string",
              "createdAt": 1482001260853
            },
            {
              "text": "Another string",
              "createdAt": 1482001260854
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "visitorId": "76672242",
          "messages": [
            {
              "text": "A string",
              "createdAt": 1482001260855
            }
          ]
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Keeping with the structure shown above, how would I query for and update the `profile.siteVisitiors.messages` array? Currently I query and update the Collection using something like the following:

```
Meteor.users.update(
  {'profile.website': url},
  {$push: {'profile.siteMessages': msgItem}},
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('whoops!' + err)
    } else {
        //success                   
    }
});
```

How would I update the newly structured messages array? I would need to match a `User` documents `profile.website` field, match a `visitorId` in the `profile.siteVisitors` array, and then push a new element into the `messages` array, but I'm not sure how this would look as a MongoDB query.

**EDIT** I've hacked together the following which seems to work, but is very ugly. How can I improve this?

```
Meteor.users.update(
    {"profile.website" : "localhost" , "profile.siteVisitors" : {$elemMatch: {"visitorId" : data.chirpVisitorId} } },
    {$push: { "profile.siteVisitors.$.messages": {"text" : data.msg, "createdAt" : data.msg.createdAt} } },
    function(err, res) {
        if (err) {  
            console.log('failed to push ' + err)
        } else {
            console.log('success on new push ' + res)
            if (res < 1) {
                let item = {
                    "visitorId": data.chirpVisitorId,
                    "messages": [data.msg]
                }
                Meteor.users.update(
                    {"profile.website": "localhost"},
                    {$push: {'profile.siteVisitors': item}},
                    function(err, res) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            console.log(res + " updated")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$(update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator.

Try the following query:

```
db.collection.update(
    {"profile.website" : "localhost" , "profile.siteVisitors" : {$elemMatch: {"visitorId" :'76672242'} } }, 
    { $push: { "profile.siteVisitors.$.messages": {"text" : <newText>, "createdAt" : <newCreatedDate>} } } 
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that helps immensely. I had tried doing the following: `db.users.find({'profile.website': "localhost", 'profile.siteVisitors': { $elemMatch: { visitorID: "74585242" } } })`, which is essentially the same as your query, but it uses single quotes. This was returning nothing in the console. Why might that be? I had assumed quotes did not matter in this scenario.

Comment: In your query you're using `visitorID`, instead of `visitorId`.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thanks. Also, your solution does not create the `siteVisitors` array if it does not exist. Rather, it uses `profile.siteVisitors` to find the document. How can I create the `siteVisitors` array (and add the new message) if it does not already exist?

Comment: You [can't](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#upsert) use `$ operator` with `upsert`. I recommend you to use two different queries for that.